# How can i list the subscribed/registered consumers using spring kafka?

Tags: spring-kafka

I'm spring-kafka version 2.2.7-RELEASE to write the kafka Listeners (as consumers) and trying understand if we have any option in spring-kafka to directly list all the subscribed/registered consumers with the details like the consumer group, consumer lag offset etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current 2.2.x version is 2.2.10.

If you are using Spring Boot:

```java
@Bean
public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaAdmin admin, ConsumerFactory<String, String> cf) {
    return args -> {
        Consumer<String, String> consumer = cf.createConsumer("group", "clientId", "");
        try (AdminClient client = AdminClient.create(admin.getConfig())) {
            Collection<ConsumerGroupListing> groups = client.listConsumerGroups()
                    .all()
                    .get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            groups.forEach(group -> {
                Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata> map = null;
                try {
                    map = client.listConsumerGroupOffsets(group.groupId())
                            .partitionsToOffsetAndMetadata()
                            .get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch (TimeoutException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Map<TopicPartition, Long> endOffsets = consumer.endOffsets(map.keySet());
                map.forEach((tp, off) -> {
                    System.out.println("group: " + group + " tp: " + tp
                            + " current offset: " + off.offset()
                            + " end offset: " + endOffsets.get(tp));
                });
            });
        }
        finally {
            consumer.close();
        }
    };
}
```

If you are not using Spring Boot, use `AdminClient.create()` to create an admin, create a consumer, and do the same.

Comment: thanks for the response. I've a question here. I see the option to fetch the list of ConsumerGroupListings but I didn't see any option to see the actual consumers. I'm looking for the consumers that were supposed to be created when I use @KafkaListener annotation on a method

Comment: There are several ways to get that information. For example, you can add an event listener and receive a [`ConsumerStartedEvent`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.3.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#lifecycle-events). There is a bug in the documentation; that event is not listed [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.3.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#events). You can also call `metrics()` on the listener container an receive a map of metrics with an entry per consumer, keyed by the client.id (the metrics has lag information).

Comment: let me give you little more background on this. I'm writing component tests using testcontainers to test my producer and consumer code. sometimes my tests are failing because the consumer is not invoked by the time my assertions are invoked. so, I'm trying to understand why this is happening intermittently

Comment: You CAN wait in your tests until you receive a `ConsumerStartedEvent`; you should also set `ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG` to `earliest` to be sure your consumer will get any records published before it starts.

Comment: I can check for ConsumerStartedEvent. Setting ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG to earliest might not be a good option for me in prod because as per my understanding, it would process the records more than once if had to stop and start the consumer app because of some reason. Please suggest

Comment: and it seems the event ConsumerStartedEvent is not available in spring-kafka 2.2.7-RELEASE

Comment: Correct; it's a new event in 2.3. Another solution is to add a `ConsumerRebalanceListener` to the listener container and wait for `onPartitionsAssigned()` to be called.